# Associatation between : SpringIocContainer | ApplicationContext | WebApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, ioc-container

**BackGround**

After reading from [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639842/how-exactly-are-the-root-context-and-the-dispatcher-servlet-context-into-a-sprin) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21319450/spring-root-application-context-and-servlet-context-confusion) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11708967/what-is-the-difference-between-applicationcontext-and-webapplicationcontext-in-s) [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652090/difference-between-applicationcontext-xml-and-spring-servlet-xml-in-spring-frame) [5](http://www.deroneriksson.com/tutorials/java/spring/introduction-to-the-spring-framework/configuring-root-web-application-context-in-spring-web-application) [6](http://www.codesenior.com/en/tutorial/Spring-ContextLoaderListener-And-DispatcherServlet-Concepts) Links I reached the following conclusion-

As Spring mvc designed over `standered servlets`,and facilitate same functionality of `servlet context` and `application context`.In spring there is two type of context `ApplicationContext` and `WebApplicationContext`-

`ApplicationContext` initialise by `ContextLoaderListener`,single instanse per application.
`WebApplicationContext` loaded by per `DispatcherServlet`.

We can understand above like this `ApplicationContext` extends by `WebApplicationContext` so what ever stuff associated with `ApplicationContext` at the end this is part of `WebApplicationContext`.

**Doubts**

1. `ApplicationContextAware` offers which `context` object.

   ```
   public class SomeThing implements ApplicationContextAware {
       @Override
       public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ctx) throws BeanException {
           //this context object is `ApplicationContext` or `WebApplicationContext`?
       }
   }
   ```
2. `context` and `container` seems synonyms to most of us,I want to
   give an example.Let say we have two dispatcher servlet one for
   `rest` and other for `mvc`.

   **First Dispatcher**-

   ```
   public class RestInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
       @Override
       protected String[] getServletMappings() {
           return new String[] { "/rest/*" };
       }
   }
   ```

   **Second Dispatcher**-

   ```
   public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
       @Override
       protected String[] getServletMappings() {
           return new String[] {
               "/mvc/*"
           };
       }
   }
   ```

   than here there is two instance of `WebApplicationContext`,those
   common part is loaded by `ContextLoaderListner` as define in
   `rootContext`.

   **I am not sure, but there must not be 2 IocContainer in a single SpringApplication.**
3. BeanFactory ie SpringIocContainer is,where all the bean object
   lives,what  ever objects we associates with `WebApplicationContext` is
   part of Spring container,how does this container initialised by
   `WebApplicationContext`?I want to want to know how does they both
   associated with each other?

   And whenever we did `ctx.getBean()`- this returns object from spring
   container,how does this communication between context and container
   happens?

There is a similar [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10303413/what-is-the-difference-between-a-spring-application-context-and-a-spring-contain) that denies the both are same,it says

> Spring comes with several container implementations,Both load bean definitions, wire beans together, and dispense beans upon request,but an ApplicationContext offers much more.

**So my point is why Both load bean definitions, wire beans together,this is kind of rework?**

One more thing even though web-app is spring driven or not, there must be a context which `standard servlet` provides and used in Http communication......

Spring follows this or spring handles this in some other manner.And in spring `context` means a just `IOC container`, of which some part is loaded by `DispacherServlet` and some part is loaded by `ContextLoaderListner` and can facilitate much more such as `I18N`,`access to static resource` etc..

Comment: A `WebApplicationContext` is an `ApplicationContext`. Both the `ContextLoaderLIstener` and `DispatcherServlet` load an instance of `WebApplicationContext` (which actually is an interface). There is only an `ApplicationContext` regardless of the fact if it is web or non web related. The `ApplicationContext` IS the container.

Comment: @M.Deinum As you pointed there is a single `context` per application,there is lots of whitepapers those explained existence of both,some of them mentioned in question itself.Moreover if you initialize your context by `DispatcherServlet` only ie no `ContextLoaderListner` ans call spring security `<sec:authorize access="isAuthenticated()">` this will throw `IllegalStateException: No ApplicationContext found:`

Comment: No I nowhere pointed to that there is a single context... But spring only has the notion of an `ApplicationContext`.. Which can be of type `WebApplicationContext`. There can be 1 or 100. What I hinted at that both the `ContextLoaderListener` and `DispatcherServlet` load a `WebApplicationContext`. The `ContextLoaderLIstener` loads a context generally called the root context, which is also what filters can access. You can also make it that (if you have one `DispatcherServlet` to expose that one as the root context (and that is generally what people forget leading to the issue you point at)).

Comment: @M.Deinum I cant understand how a IOC container be a `context`.IOC container is springs memory management design and more.. which takes care of instantiation of beans.even though application is spring driven or not there must be a `context` that standered servlet facilitate.What I thinks,`context` access bean object from `IocContainer` or vice versa.

Comment: No it isn't. You are confusing servlet context with a spring context / container / application context. Spring has no ties (basically) to the servlet context, heck you could even use Spring in a standalone application. Hence from the spring pov the `ApplicationContext` is the IOC Container is the context.

Comment: I never compare servlet tech specific context with spring context,my concern was with `Standered Servlet Context` which is the core `HTTP`,now you again saying container is context,my doubt is `rootContext` or 'webaplicationContext'.Also what `WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(myServlet.getServletContext())` achieves?

Comment: check out if this link helps with your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41550796/spring-where-does-autowired-look-for-beans/41552579#41552579

Answer (score 1):

**For Your Doubt 1**

In an spring application there is a single instance of context Which is `WebAplicationCntext` per `DispatcherServlet`.Which can be refer by a super Interface `ApplicationContext`-

```
public class SomeThing implements ApplicationContextAware{
@Override
public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ctx) throws BeanException{
//this context object is `WebApplicationContext` which is refer by `ApplicationContext`.
 }
}
```

**In spring , context means a just IOC container, of which some part is loaded by DispacherServlet and some part is loaded by ContextLoaderListner and can facilitate much more such as I18N,access to static resource etc**

Your above understanding is almost correct.In Spring All the `WebApplicationContext` object shares some common reference which is `rootContext`.

This answer desn't include answer of `doubt2`, `doubt3` ,and `why all context perform same task`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, in a spring MVC application the spring contexts are registered in the servlet context of the web application. You can do that in the `web.xml` file setting the spring `ContextLoaderListener` or with java configuration. In the comments I pointed out this link where it explains how this is done via java configuration classes:

[spring: where does `@autowired` look for beans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41550796/spring-where-does-autowired-look-for-beans/41552579#41552579)

There you can see how the 'connection' is done. Then, you asked in the comments what this achieves:

```
WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(myServle‌​t.getServletContext(‌​))
```

If you check the code of that class you can see it gets the `WebApplicationContext` from the attributes of the `ServletContext`. These attributes are set in the initialization of the web application. If you notice, in the `ContextLoader` class (parent of `ContextLoaderListener`), in the `initWebApplicationContext` method it sets these attributes to the servlet context:

```
/**
     * Initialize Spring's web application context for the given servlet context,
     * using the application context provided at construction time, or creating a new one
     * according to the "{@link #CONTEXT_CLASS_PARAM contextClass}" and
     * "{@link #CONFIG_LOCATION_PARAM contextConfigLocation}" context-params.
     * @param servletContext current servlet context
     * @return the new WebApplicationContext
     * @see #ContextLoader(WebApplicationContext)
     * @see #CONTEXT_CLASS_PARAM
     * @see #CONFIG_LOCATION_PARAM
     */
    public WebApplicationContext initWebApplicationContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
        if (servletContext.getAttribute(WebApplicationContext.ROOT_WEB_APPLICATION_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE) != null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "Cannot initialize context because there is already a root application context present - " +
                    "check whether you have multiple ContextLoader* definitions in your web.xml!");
        }

        Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(ContextLoader.class);
        servletContext.log("Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext");
        if (logger.isInfoEnabled()) {
            logger.info("Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started");
        }
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        try {
            // Store context in local instance variable, to guarantee that
            // it is available on ServletContext shutdown.
            if (this.context == null) {
                this.context = createWebApplicationContext(servletContext);
            }
            if (this.context instanceof ConfigurableWebApplicationContext) {
                ConfigurableWebApplicationContext cwac = (ConfigurableWebApplicationContext) this.context;
                if (!cwac.isActive()) {
                    // The context has not yet been refreshed -> provide services such as
                    // setting the parent context, setting the application context id, etc
                    if (cwac.getParent() == null) {
                        // The context instance was injected without an explicit parent ->
                        // determine parent for root web application context, if any.
                        ApplicationContext parent = loadParentContext(servletContext);
                        cwac.setParent(parent);
                    }
                    configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(cwac, servletContext);
                }
            }
            servletContext.setAttribute(WebApplicationContext.ROOT_WEB_APPLICATION_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE, this.context);

            ClassLoader ccl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
            if (ccl == ContextLoader.class.getClassLoader()) {
                currentContext = this.context;
            }
            else if (ccl != null) {
                currentContextPerThread.put(ccl, this.context);
            }

            if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                logger.debug("Published root WebApplicationContext as ServletContext attribute with name [" +
                        WebApplicationContext.ROOT_WEB_APPLICATION_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE + "]");
            }
            if (logger.isInfoEnabled()) {
                long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
                logger.info("Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in " + elapsedTime + " ms");
            }

            return this.context;
        }
        catch (RuntimeException ex) {
            logger.error("Context initialization failed", ex);
            servletContext.setAttribute(WebApplicationContext.ROOT_WEB_APPLICATION_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE, ex);
            throw ex;
        }
        catch (Error err) {
            logger.error("Context initialization failed", err);
            servletContext.setAttribute(WebApplicationContext.ROOT_WEB_APPLICATION_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE, err);
            throw err;
        }
    }
```

That is done in this line:

```
servletContext.setAttribute(WebApplicationContext.ROOT_WEB_APPLICATION_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE, this.context);
```

As you can see, it is stored in the same place where you are trying to get it with the `WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(myServle‌​t.getServletContext(‌​))` :

```
/**
     * Find the root {@code WebApplicationContext} for this web app, typically
     * loaded via {@link org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener}.
     * <p>Will rethrow an exception that happened on root context startup,
     * to differentiate between a failed context startup and no context at all.
     * @param sc ServletContext to find the web application context for
     * @return the root WebApplicationContext for this web app, or {@code null} if none
     * @see org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext#ROOT_WEB_APPLICATION_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE
     */
    public static WebApplicationContext getWebApplicationContext(ServletContext sc) {
        return getWebApplicationContext(sc, WebApplicationContext.ROOT_WEB_APPLICATION_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE);
    }
```

So as you can see all the answers to your doubts are in the code that spring executes during the startup of the web application.

Hope I answered your question.